# How to create a file on Android Internal Storage?

Tags: android, file, storage, internal

I want to save a file on internal storage into a specific folder. My code is:

```
File mediaDir = new File("media");
if (!mediaDir.exists()){
   mediaDir.createNewFile();
   mediaDir.mkdir();

}
File f = new File(getLocalPath());
f.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
fos.write(data);
fos.close();
```

`getLocalPath` returns `/data/data/myPackage/files/media/qmhUZU.jpg` but when I want to create the media folder I'm getting the exception "java.io.IOException: Read-only file system". Any ideas how to write my files on internal phone storage in in folder media? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to create the path /media, you cannot - not unless the phone is rooted. Apps are not allowed to write into the root folder.

Comment: a file I was able to create but a folder not. is there a restriction for folders?

Comment: For those that need a full tutorial: http://chrisrisner.com/31-Days-of-Android--Day-23%E2%80%93Writing-and-Reading-Files

Answer (score 23):

You should use [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) like this:

```
ContextWrapper cw = new ContextWrapper(context);
File directory = cw.getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

As always, refer to [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html), [ContextWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html) has a lot to offer.

Comment: I didn't understand one thing, how is it different from calling the same method of the original context?

Comment: ContextWrapper is just a proxy to the original context. The benefit here is that you can subclass ContextWrapper to achieve some custom behavior, so that say getDir() actually returns some other (non-standard) directory. You are right that one can use Context directly tho'.

Answer (score 2):

You should create the `media` dir appended to what `getLocalPath()` returns.

Comment: no, it's not a solution because the file doesn't exists and I want to create it

Comment: No, it is a solution - you have to create the folder before you can write files within it.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same exact error as well.  Here is the fix.  When you are specifying where to write to, Android will automatically resolve your path into either `/data/` or `/mnt/sdcard/`.  Let me explain.

If you execute the following statement:

```
File resolveMe = new File("/data/myPackage/files/media/qmhUZU.jpg");
resolveMe.createNewFile();
```

It will resolve the path to the root `/data/` somewhere higher up in Android.

I figured this out, because after I executed the following code, it was placed automatically in the root `/mnt/` without me translating anything on my own.

```
File resolveMeSDCard = new File("/sdcard/myPackage/files/media/qmhUZU.jpg");
resolveMeSDCard.createNewFile();
```

A quick fix would be to change your following code:

```
File f = new File(getLocalPath().replace("/data/data/", "/"));
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is replacing a very bad idea with a slightly less bad idea, but still unwise - ordinarily application should just not be assuming absolute paths, but rather discovering the applicable ones at runtime using the provided APIs.

Answer (score 0):

**Write a file**

When saving a file to internal storage, you can acquire the appropriate directory as a File by calling one of two methods:

*getFilesDir()*

```
      Returns a File representing an internal directory for your app.
```

*getCacheDir()*

```
     Returns a File representing an internal directory for your 
     app's temporary cache files.
     Be sure to delete each file once it is no longer needed and implement a reasonable 
     size limit for the amount of memory you use at any given time, such as 1MB.
```

Caution: If the system runs low on storage, it may delete your cache files without warning.

Answer (score -3):

Hi try this it will create directory + file inside it

```
File mediaDir = new File("/sdcard/download/media");
if (!mediaDir.exists()){
    mediaDir.mkdir();
}

File resolveMeSDCard = new File("/sdcard/download/media/hello_file.txt");
resolveMeSDCard.createNewFile();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(resolveMeSDCard);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();

System.out.println("Your file has been written");
```

Comment: /sdcard and internal storage (which is what this question was about) are two totally different things.

Comment: yeah, the question was about something else

Comment: This is not about external storage!