# MediaPlayer error -2147483648 when playing file on internal storage

Tags: android, media-player

I'm using the [Audio Capture sample on android.com](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html) to record and play back audio on actual devices.  (Motorola touch pad, and Samsung Galaxy S).

When I define the audio file path as

```
mFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
```

record and playback works.

But if I set the audio file as

```
mFile = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
```

[OR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017292/android-create-file-on-internal-storage/5018107#5018107)

```
mFile = getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();
```

OR

```
mFile = getDir("media", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE).getAbsolutePath();
```

record seems to work, but playback fails with

> ERROR/MediaPlayer(4559): error (1, -2147483648)

**What function will return the correct *internal storage* directory to save audio files for playback *only within my app*?**

The code in question is in my `onCreate` function.   (In the example, they have it in the Constructor, but I moved it to onCreate because otherwise getFilesDir() and getDir() have no context to work.)

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

//  mFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();     // OK
//  mFile = getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();                                 // BAD
//  mFile = getDir("media", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getAbsolutePath();         // BAD
    mFile = getDir("media", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE).getAbsolutePath();  // BAD
    mFile += "/audiorecordtest.3gp";
    Log.e(LOG_TAG,mFile);
//  ...
}
```

When I record to external storage (and playback works properly), the log looks like this:

```
06-17 10:07:30.890: DEBUG/AudioHardwareTegra(85): getInputBufferSize: returns 320 for rate 8000
06-17 10:07:30.900: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): limits: 2147483647/0 bytes/us, bit rate: 12200 bps and the estimated moov size 3072 bytes
06-17 10:07:30.960: DEBUG/AudioHardwareTegra(85): setDriver_l: Analog mic? yes. Bluetooth? no.
06-17 10:07:31.100: WARN/AudioFlinger(85): RecordThread: buffer overflow
06-17 10:07:31.100: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): setStartTimestampUs: 86380
06-17 10:07:31.100: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): Earliest track starting time: 86380
06-17 10:07:34.350: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Stopping Audio track
06-17 10:07:34.450: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): Received total/0-length (167/0) buffers and encoded 167 frames. - audio
06-17 10:07:34.450: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): Audio track drift time: -20309 us
06-17 10:07:34.450: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Stopping Audio track source
06-17 10:07:34.470: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Audio track stopped
06-17 10:07:34.470: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Stopping writer thread
06-17 10:07:34.470: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): 0 chunks are written in the last batch
06-17 10:07:34.470: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Writer thread stopped
06-17 10:07:34.470: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Stopping Audio track
06-17 10:07:34.470: WARN/MediaRecorder(4472): mediarecorder went away with unhandled events
06-17 10:07:40.310: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(85): setDataSource('/mnt/sdcard/audiorecordtest.3gp')
06-17 10:07:46.590: DEBUG/AudioHardwareTegra(85): AudioStreamOutTegra::flush()
06-17 10:07:46.670: DEBUG/AudioHardwareTegra(85): AudioStreamOutTegra::flush() returns
```

When I record to internal storage (and it fails), the log looks like this:

```
06-17 10:08:28.380: DEBUG/AudioHardwareTegra(85): getInputBufferSize: returns 320 for rate 8000
06-17 10:08:28.380: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): limits: 2147483647/0 bytes/us, bit rate: 12200 bps and the estimated moov size 3072 bytes
06-17 10:08:28.440: DEBUG/AudioHardwareTegra(85): setDriver_l: Analog mic? yes. Bluetooth? no.
06-17 10:08:28.970: WARN/AudioFlinger(85): RecordThread: buffer overflow
06-17 10:08:28.970: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): setStartTimestampUs: 83095
06-17 10:08:28.970: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): Earliest track starting time: 83095
06-17 10:08:34.020: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Stopping Audio track
06-17 10:08:34.080: WARN/AudioFlinger(85): RecordThread: buffer overflow
06-17 10:08:34.090: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): Received total/0-length (257/0) buffers and encoded 257 frames. - audio
06-17 10:08:34.090: INFO/MPEG4Writer(85): Audio track drift time: -385311 us
06-17 10:08:34.090: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Stopping Audio track source
06-17 10:08:34.090: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Audio track stopped
06-17 10:08:34.090: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Stopping writer thread
06-17 10:08:34.090: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): 0 chunks are written in the last batch
06-17 10:08:34.090: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Writer thread stopped
06-17 10:08:34.090: DEBUG/MPEG4Writer(85): Stopping Audio track
06-17 10:08:34.100: WARN/MediaRecorder(4559): mediarecorder went away with unhandled events
06-17 10:08:40.740: INFO/StagefrightPlayer(85): setDataSource('/data/data/my.record.test/files/audiorecordtest.3gp')
06-17 10:08:40.740: ERROR/MediaPlayer(4559): error (1, -2147483648)
06-17 10:08:40.740: ERROR/AudioRecordTest(4559): prepare() failed
```

The recording sections of the log look largely the same to me, so I think it's recording, but I don't know how to check the file in any way besides play it.  ;-)

The error log is similar when I use getDir().

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Thanks to gtkandroid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3038474/can-a-videoview-play-a-video-stored-on-internal-storage/5475436#5475436):

Instead of `mPlayer.setDataSource(mFile);` I did this:

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
mPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());         
fileInputStream.close();
mPlayer.prepare();
```

Comment: Thanks guys for the .close() suggestion; I just added it to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Tim Crowley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870947/tim-crowley) is right. Better practice is to close the stream, like this:

```
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(path);
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(stream.getFD());
stream.close();
```

It is noted in the documentation of the method:

`android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(FileDescriptor fd)`

> Sets the data source (`FileDescriptor`) to use. It is the caller's
>   responsibility to **close** the file descriptor. It is safe to do so **as
>   soon as this call returns**.