# Can't get media player to work when SD drive is not installed

Tags: android

First I make a call to

```
get_fullPathToAudio();
```

to determine the path of where an audio file was downloaded.

```
public File get_fullPathToAudioAsFile()
    {       
        File storageFile = this.getExternalFilesDir(null);
        if (storageFile == null)
        {
            // no external storage so store on private path
            storageFile =  this.getFilesDir();
        }
        return storageFile;
    }
    public String get_fullPathToAudio() {

        return get_fullPathToAudioAsFile() + File.separator +  this.get_currentArticleAudioFileName();
    }


String filePath = this.myApp.get_fullPathToAudio();
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();
```

All works well if I have an SD drive on my emulator but when I don't have an emulator the function

```
get_fullPathToAudioAsFile();
```

uses

```
getFilesDir();
```

instead of

```
getExternalFilesDir(null);
```

which returns a path to my private drive where my app is installed. I can see the file in
data/data/com.myapp/files/myfile.m4a

for example. Is there a different way to play an audio file if it's not on the SD drive?

The error messsage I get is

error(-1, -2147483648)
Could not open file null for playback

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way

```
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(mFile);
mPlayer.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());         
mPlayer.prepare();
```

[MediaPlayer error -2147483648 when playing file on internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380765/mediaplayer-error-2147483648-when-playing-file-on-internal-storage)