# How to get continuous frames from a video file input?

Tags: java, android, video, frame

I had done with taking video as input. Now decided to get frames with it, so I used `MediaMetadataRetriever()`. After using this got only first frame. So can anybody suggest me the remedy?

```
String STR = (String) Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(STR+"/vd.3gpp");

img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1); 
img.setImageBitmap(retriever.getFrameAtTime(1000,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_NEXT_SYNC));
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

At this point:

```
img.setImageBitmap(retriever.getFrameAtTime(1000,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_NEXT_SYNC));
```

You are retrieving exactly one frame and setting exactly one bitmap.
What you need is a loop, like:

```
int videoLength = /* get video length from some where */
for(int i = 0; i < videoLength; i *= 1000000)
{
    img.setImageBitmap(retriever.getFrameAtTime(1000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_NEXT_SYNC));
}
```

Comment: I added a loop like this before but getting the videolength is the critical one.. can you help me in getting the value of videolength.

Comment: @user3217889 I don't have a android system here so I can't try. But [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19689553/how-to-read-length-of-video-recorded-with-mediarecorder-into-private-app-storage) are 2 solutions to your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. let me check out once.