# Writing object to internal storage in android (Inside new directory)

Tags: android, serialization, android-sdcard, outputstream, objectoutputstream

I've seen how to write to internal storage using this method..

```
public void storeSerializedObject(MyObject theObject) {



        FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
        String fileName = theObject.getName();
        try {


            fileOut = context.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput(
                    fileName + ".ser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(theObject);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();

        } catch (IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

The thing is I want to place theObject in some new specified directory.
Then eventually search that directory for all .ser files, and deserialize each object.
So basically, how would you do that?

Also, using the above approach to file storing, is there a way to check that default unnamed location for a list of all filenames within its contents?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017292/android-create-file-on-internal-storage

Comment: you want to create directory for internal storage files?

Comment: Essentially yes.  However the above code does not allow you to create or change the directory for the object you're writing.  The OpenFileOutput() I don't think can work for what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Context` has several ways to get internal files and directories, you may want to use [`Context#getDir()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getDir%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).

`getDir("serfiles", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)` should result in a directory named
`/data/data/your.package.name/app_serfiles`

To list files in there use `File#list()` or `File#listFiles()`. Combine that with a filter in case you want just specific files

```
private static File[] listSerFiles(Context context, String dirName) {
    File dir = context.getDir(dirName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return dir.listFiles(SER_FILTER);
}
private static final FileFilter SER_FILTER = new FileFilter() {
    public boolean accept(File file) {
        return file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".ser");
    }
};
```

And you could open outputstream like

```
private static FileOutputStream getOutputStreamInDir(Context context, String dirName, String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    File dir = context.getDir(dirName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    File file = new File(dir, fileName);
    return new FileOutputStream(file);
}
```