# Saving data in android

Tags: android, arraylist, save

I the last i've been creating some sort of a "contacts" app. In the main activity i have created a listview that syncronises itself with an ArrayList of strings(names). To add names to the the listview i created another activity. I have managed to get the two activities to talk to each other(send the name(the string) to the "list" activity), but i am struggeling to find a way to save the the ArrayList.

The problem is that every time the "list" activity is leaved and then resumed all the old content disappears.

So, i guess i need a good way to save an ArrayList?

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here:

[Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

[Saving Data](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html)

Also, I recommend to use [JSON](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html), if you decide to store your list in file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **SharedPreferences** class ,**Internal Storage** ,**External storage** or **SQLite**.

This is good tutorial for SQLite: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

This is how to use SharedPreferences: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

This is how to write a file in external storage: [Write a file in external storage in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330276/write-a-file-in-external-storage-in-android)

This is how to write a file in internal storage:[How to create a file on Android Internal Storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5017292/android-create-file-on-internal-storage)

**Don't forget permission for external and internal storage.**

I mean it's better to use **SQLite** for data like a contact.